# "if search in text: " is not working when PDF text is being matched in excel using pyPDF2

Tags: python, excel, if-statement, pdf, pypdf

So I am trying to check if the content of the rows I have in excel is matching the content of the PDF file.

My excel file looks like this:

```
Content      Y/N
I AM NAME     Yes
I AM NAME;    No
```

Using the code below:

However, it doesn't read anything. All the results say `'NO'`

Anyone who can help me with this?

```
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(FILE)
text = [0]


for page in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
    page_1 = pdf_reader.getPage(page)   
    text.append(page_1.extractText())

     
length = len(df['Conditions'])

 for i in range (0, length):
        search = df['Content'][i]
        if search in text:
            df ['Y/N'][i] = 'Yes'
       
        else:
            df ['Y/N'][i] = 'No'
```

Comment: Check what you test and what you test against are the same, a common issue is leading or trailing spaces.